# Do the bigger maps still have only 10 buildings?

Tags: die2nite

Since v1.2, some towns have a 25*25grid, in stead of the old 12*12.

did the amount of buildings go up in these big maps or is it harder to find buildings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posts on the hero forums have confirmed that larger maps can have more buildings.  No confirmed report of the exact numbers but some people have reported up to 27x27 maps, and 15+ buildings.